# How to implement a class attribute with an enum value

Tags: python

I have a class `Meal` which implements two attributes, and namely `name`(e.g. 'Pizza') and `kind`(e.g. 'Italian'). Now, the kind has to be one of the ones I specify (so that it becomes like a tag for my app). Possibly I will implement name in the same way.

Also, to initiate the class, I want to pass the name and the kind of meal.

Now I have made some research and I think the way to do what I want is to specify the different kinds as enumerated constants.

The only thing is that I can't find how to implement an enum as an attribute in python, I can only find examples for iterate on a list.

Is it possible to do what I am looking for with enum?

Here is the code I have written so far, but I can't figure out how to make it work

```
from enum import Enum


class Kind(Enum):
    ITALIAN = 1
    FISH_AND_CHIPS = 2
    CHINESE = 3
    INDIAN = 4


class Meal:
    def __init__(self, name, Kind):
        self.name = name
        self.kind = Kind
```

Comment: Please update the question with the reason you can't `figure out how to make it work`

Comment: In how far is this related to instance attributes at all? It appears you basically want to enforce the type of a variable. So do you want this checked, do you want an error thrown on wrong assignment, or what else do you consider valid specification of values? If you don't want any enforcement, you can assign Enum Members just like any other value - e.g. ``self.kind = Kind.ITALIAN``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi basically this is going to be a Django model, I want a restaurant owner to insert food in the menu, but to avoid having wrong splelled kinds, I would like them to use something like a serch box with suggestions which are inside this given set.

Comment: It seems like what you want is input validation/sanitisation/checking, not something deep inside your model code.

Comment: To be fair, I was thinking that probably the best way to do this (in Django) would be through a list or radio buttons. I am so confused trying to learn Django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `getattr` for this:

```
from enum import Enum


class Kind(Enum):
    ITALIAN = 1
    FISH_AND_CHIPS = 2
    CHINESE = 3
    INDIAN = 4


class Meal:
    def __init__(self, name, kind):
        self.name = name
        self.kind = getattr(Kind, kind.upper())

italian_pizza = Meal(name='Pizza', kind='Italian')
```

Although I feel like the real question is *why not use lists/dictionaries* for this - they're much more Python-friendly than enums.

Comment: I was trying to use a list, but then I don't know where to pace the if statement to check if the kind specified is within the list